# Which are isomorphic to induced subgraphs of G?

Tags: graph-theory

Question: Determine which of $H_1$, $H_2$ and $H_3$ are subgraphs of
the following graph G. Which are induced subgraphs of G? Which are
isomorphic to subgraphs of G? **Which are isomorphic to induced subgraphs
of G?**
[image]

**Answer:**
I understand that none of $H_1$, $H_2$, $H_3$ are induced subgraphs, but in regards to which are isomorphic to induced subgraphs of G... I understand that $H_1$ isn't as there's no edge between vertex b and f, $H_3$ is isomorphic to the induced subgraph of G, as all edges are included... but $H_2$ confuses me, as the paths are there (i.e. b can go to through vertex e to get to c), but for it to be induced subgraph, doesn't $b$ have to be directly adjacent to c? The answer says that it is isomoprhic to the induced subgraph of G... but I don't understand how.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with isomorphisms of induced subgraphs, you want to temporarily forget the letters on the $H$ graphs and just ask yourself if there are induced subgraphs of $G$ that have that "shape".

- You're right that $G$ induced by $\{A,B,C,E\}$ is isomorphic to $H_3$.
- You're also right that there is no induced subgraph of $G$ that is isomorphic to $H_1$, but your argument is incomplete.  You need to show that *any* subgraph of $G$ induced by the vertices of a 4-cycle would have an extra edge or edges.  That's not too hard: you can argue that the vertices of a 4-cycle in $G$ are either $\{B,C,E,F\}$ or exactly one of the vertices is either $A$ or $D$, and in each of those cases you can identify an edge in the induced subgraph that is not a part of the 4-cycle.
- In the same way, for $H_2$, you need to decide whether there is a 4-path in $G$ where the induced subgraph just has those three edges.  (Hint: yes.)

As an aside, that font where $c$ looks so much like $e$ needs to die in a fire.

Comment: "that font where c looks so much like e needs to die in a fire." - because then Xerox copiers will regularly switch them up?

Comment: @JohnDvorak never mind AI, **I** had to squint to see which was which!